# Python Tkinter. Best Fit Ellipse from Data Points

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, bmp

I am working on a Python GUI w/ Tkinter. I am trying to save four specified point locations from a BMP image into variables, and create a best-fit ellipse that more or less passes through the saved points. I am still a beginner working w/ Tkinter and GUI's so please bear w/ me!

So far, the code is able to mark the points and print out its position/coordinates. Should I use matplotlib for this kind of situation? Am i able to use that w/ tkinter as well?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.pos = []
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.counter = 0

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        analyze = Menu(menu)

        analyze.add_command(label="Region of 
        Interest",command=self.regionOfInterest)
        analyze.add_command(label="Erase", command=self.erasePoints)

        menu.add_cascade(label="Analyze", menu=analyze)
        load = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

    def regionOfInterest(self):
        root.config(cursor="plus")
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.imgClick)

    def erasePoints(self):
        self.pos = []

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def imgClick(self, event):

        if self.counter < 4:
            x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
            y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
            self.pos.append((x, y))
            print(self.pos)
            canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", 
tags="crosshair")
            canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", 
tags="crosshair")
            self.counter += 1
        else:
            canvas.unbind("<Button 1>")
            root.config(cursor="arrow")
            self.counter = 0


root = Tk()
imgSize = Image.open("ap41.ddr.brf.sdat.bmp")
tkimage =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgSize)
w, h = imgSize.size

canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
canvas.create_image((w/2,h/2),image=tkimage)
canvas.pack()

root.geometry("%dx%d"%(w,h))
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello again FLCL. Have you tried using the data with `create_oval()`

Comment: I just updated my answer. I had a mistake that needed fixing.

Comment: 4 points isn't enough to define a unique ellipse, 5 is the minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can play with and fine tune but I think this will be close to what you are trying to do.

first I created anther menu item labeled `Create Ellipse` that links to a method to work out the top left cords and bottom right cords and then uses that with the `create_ovel()` command to create an ellipse on the screen. Let me know if this is close to what you want to do.

The new method below will compare the values of each tuple to a base tuple and if the numbers are lower it will change the top left cords and if the numbers are high it will change the bottom right cords. With those 2 sets of cords figured out it will then create an ellipse to roughly fit what you selected.

```
def createEllipse(self):

    top_left_cords = self.pos[0]
    bottom_right_cords = self.pos[0]
    for pos in self.pos:
        if pos[0] < top_left_cords[0]:
            top_left_cords = (pos[0], top_left_cords[1])

        if pos[1] < top_left_cords[1]:
            top_left_cords = (top_left_cords[0], pos[1])

        if pos[0] > bottom_right_cords[0]:
            bottom_right_cords = (pos[0], bottom_right_cords[1])

        if pos[1] > bottom_right_cords[1]:
            bottom_right_cords = (bottom_right_cords[0], pos[1])
```

Below is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.pos = []
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.counter = 0

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.client_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        analyze = Menu(menu)

        analyze.add_command(label="Region of Interest",command=self.regionOfInterest)
        analyze.add_command(label="Erase", command=self.erasePoints)
        analyze.add_command(label="Create Ellipse", command=self.createEllipse)

        menu.add_cascade(label="Analyze", menu=analyze)
        load = Image.open("./Colors/1.png")
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)


        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)

    def createEllipse(self):

        top_left_cords = self.pos[0]
        bottom_right_cords = self.pos[0]
        for pos in self.pos:
            if pos[0] < top_left_cords[0]:
                top_left_cords = (pos[0], top_left_cords[1])

            if pos[1] < top_left_cords[1]:
                top_left_cords = (top_left_cords[0], pos[1])

            if pos[0] > bottom_right_cords[0]:
                bottom_right_cords = (pos[0], bottom_right_cords[1])

            if pos[1] > bottom_right_cords[1]:
                bottom_right_cords = (bottom_right_cords[0], pos[1])

        print(top_left_cords, bottom_right_cords)

        canvas.create_oval(top_left_cords, bottom_right_cords)

    def regionOfInterest(self):
        root.config(cursor="plus")
        canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.imgClick)

    def erasePoints(self):
        self.pos = []

    def client_exit(self):
        exit()

    def imgClick(self, event):

        if self.counter < 4:
            x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
            y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
            self.pos.append((x, y))
            print(self.pos)
            canvas.create_line(x - 5, y, x + 5, y, fill="red", 
tags="crosshair")
            canvas.create_line(x, y - 5, x, y + 5, fill="red", 
tags="crosshair")
            self.counter += 1
        else:
            canvas.unbind("<Button 1>")
            root.config(cursor="arrow")
            self.counter = 0


root = Tk()
imgSize = Image.open("./Colors/1.png")
tkimage =  ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgSize)
w, h = imgSize.size

canvas = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
canvas.create_image((w/2,h/2),image=tkimage)
canvas.pack()

root.geometry("%dx%d"%(w,h))
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is a before and after from a sample image I have for testing.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Hello again! Sorry about the late reply. Thank you for the detailed run through of your code! The ellipse unfortunately doesn't display on the bmp image w/ the marked points when I try to run it, however it does still print out the values for the top_left_cords & bottom_right_cords so i do believe it works! I have a feeling it has to do w/ the canvas maybe.

Comment: @FLCL hum. Well it works for me. I just changed the image to something I could test with. I added a before and after image from my side of the testing.

Comment: @FLCL Did you use the new menu button for creating the ellipse?

Comment: Got it working! Just had a small syntax error on my end. Thank you again! :)